# Handling user settings with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Currently i'm developing an `WPF` application with the `MVVM-light` framework.

On this moment i'm setting my settings as shown in the next example code in my viewmodel:

```
private string _property

public string Property
{
    get { return _property; }
    set
    {
        if (_property != value)
        {
            _property = value;
            Settings.Default.Property = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }
}
```

I save my settings on application exit:

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Everything works as intended, but ...

**Question:** Is this a correct approach or is there a better way of handling settings in MVVM

Comment: You can bind directly to settings `{x:Static Settings.Default.Whatevs}`, then in your window watch for the Close event whereupon you can save the settings.  UI settings are a View concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change your settings based on properties of your `ViewModel`, your approach would work. The only problem is that your `ViewModel` is tightly coupled with `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` class.

I would create a Wrapper class that implements an interface (say *IConfigProvider*) that exposes all your settings as Properties and the Save method and inject that into your `ViewModel`. This way, you can pass a mock\stub when you unit test your `ViewModel`.

Another benefit is that if you ever decide to change the way you store your config values (say you want to store some settings in the database), you don't need to touch your `ViewModels` as all that job is done in your `ConfigProvider` class.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simpler way... well the 'way' is the same, but rather than adding a setting for each property, just create a `Settings` class with *all* of your properties in... declare them as normal properties and implement the usual `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. *Then*, and here's the difference, create just one setting for this class. That way, it's much easier to maintain.